# Error handling using try except in Django

Tags: django, error-handling, try-except

I am trying to input a value as query. In order to handle the error, i used try except method. But I am still getting error when i give invalid entry: *Fleet matching query does not exist.*
I expect error message to be printed on the template. Am I doing something wrong? Here is my code:

```
def entry(request):

    query = request.GET.get("q")
    if query:
        query = query.replace(" ","")

        result = Fleet.objects.get(veh = query)
        try:
            trip = Trip.objects.filter(veh = result).first()
            .
            .
            . 

        except (Fleet.DoesNotExist):
            EntryTable.objects.create(veh = query, in_time = datetime.now(), purpose = 'New vehicle')
            return render(request, 'fleet/msfleet.html', {'error_message': 'New vehicle entry noted'})
    else:
        return render(request, 'fleet/msfleet.html', {'error_message': 'Enter a vehicle number'})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a closer look at the stacktrace. The line which gives an error is this one.

```
result = Fleet.objects.get(veh = query)
```

However, this line is not inside the `try` block, therefore, the exception is not catched. On a side note, you dont need any other lines inside the `try`, only the one that can raise an exception. You can either return from the `except` part, and move all other code after the try/except, or use an `else` part with try/except.

Comment: Thank you so much. That is a silly mistake from my side

Comment: Second part of your answer is helpful too :)